# Apache Mesos starts once, but once I shut it down it won't restart

Tags: apache-mesos

I have a build of Apache Mesos done on a redhat 6.6 machine. It's installed to a directory I'll call `$INST`.

I set up `$INST/etc/masters` and `$INST/etc/slaves` to have the masters and slaves' hostnames, then set up `$INST/etc/mesos-slave-env.sh` like so:

```
export MESOS_work_dir=/path/to/some/directory/$HOSTNAME/work
export MESOS_log_dir=/path/to/some/directory/$HOSTNAME/log
export MESOS_master=masternodename:5050
```

And `$INST/etc/mesos-master-env.sh` is exactly the same but without `MESOS_master` defined.

`/path/to/some/directory` can be either shared by all nodes, or unique on all nodes for the behavior that I'm experiencing.

Then I run `$INST/sbin/mesos-start-cluster` the first time. It starts. I can open `firefox masternodename:5050` and see the web UI, and it shows all of the slaves attached.

However, if I run `$INST/sbin/mesos-stop-cluster.sh` to kill the cluster, then restart it with `mesos-start-cluster.sh`, it hangs forever. `curl masternodename:5050` opens a connection to the port and waits, forever, for data and none comes. the log shows this and nothing ever progresses from here:

```
I1102 16:05:39.334799 27997 logging.cpp:172] INFO level logging started!
I1102 16:05:39.335925 27997 main.cpp:229] Build: 2015-11-02 20:29:24 by sbhaide
I1102 16:05:39.335942 27997 main.cpp:231] Version: 0.25.0
I1102 16:05:39.336308 27997 main.cpp:252] Using 'HierarchicalDRF' allocator
I1102 16:05:39.344976 27997 leveldb.cpp:176] Opened db in 7.787897ms
I1102 16:05:39.346916 27997 leveldb.cpp:183] Compacted db in 1.90886ms
I1102 16:05:39.347038 27997 leveldb.cpp:198] Created db iterator in 94694ns
I1102 16:05:39.347062 27997 leveldb.cpp:204] Seeked to beginning of db in 4003ns
I1102 16:05:39.347074 27997 leveldb.cpp:273] Iterated through 0 keys in the db in 513ns
I1102 16:05:39.347393 27997 replica.cpp:744] Replica recovered with log positions 0 -> 0 with 1 holes and 0 unlearned
I1102 16:05:39.351538 28017 recover.cpp:449] Starting replica recovery
I1102 16:05:39.352499 27997 main.cpp:465] Starting Mesos master
I1102 16:05:39.352665 28017 recover.cpp:475] Replica is in EMPTY status
I1102 16:05:39.356853 28023 replica.cpp:641] Replica in EMPTY status received a broadcasted recover request
I1102 16:05:39.356978 28025 master.cpp:376] Master 6fa2ccac-3527-4522-a72d-8eeba06f55eb (xxxxxx.xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxx.xxx) started on 10.148.0.101:5050
I1102 16:05:39.357002 28025 master.cpp:378] Flags at startup: --allocation_interval="1secs" --allocator="HierarchicalDRF" --authenticate="false" --authenticate_slaves="false" --authenticators="crammd5" --authorizers="local" --framework_sorter="drf" --help="false" --hostname_lookup="true" --initialize_driver_logging="true" --log_auto_initialize="true" --log_dir="/path/to/log/directory/xxxxxxxx/log" --logbufsecs="0" --logging_level="INFO" --max_slave_ping_timeouts="5" --port="5050" --quiet="false" --recovery_slave_removal_limit="100%" --registry="replicated_log" --registry_fetch_timeout="1mins" --registry_store_timeout="5secs" --registry_strict="false" --root_submissions="true" --slave_ping_timeout="15secs" --slave_reregister_timeout="10mins" --user_sorter="drf" --version="false" --webui_dir="/install/directory/path/share/mesos/webui" --work_dir="..." --zk_session_timeout="10secs"
I1102 16:05:39.357393 28025 master.cpp:425] Master allowing unauthenticated frameworks to register
I1102 16:05:39.357405 28025 master.cpp:430] Master allowing unauthenticated slaves to register
I1102 16:05:39.357467 28025 master.cpp:467] Using default 'crammd5' authenticator
W1102 16:05:39.357502 28025 authenticator.cpp:505] No credentials provided, authentication requests will be refused
I1102 16:05:39.358242 28025 authenticator.cpp:512] Initializing server SASL
I1102 16:05:39.359158 28011 recover.cpp:195] Received a recover response from a replica in EMPTY status
I1102 16:05:39.360354 28029 recover.cpp:566] Updating replica status to STARTING
I1102 16:05:39.361856 28016 leveldb.cpp:306] Persisting metadata (8 bytes) to leveldb took 1.183548ms
I1102 16:05:39.361889 28016 replica.cpp:323] Persisted replica status to STARTING
I1102 16:05:39.362313 28014 recover.cpp:475] Replica is in STARTING status
I1102 16:05:39.363344 28014 replica.cpp:641] Replica in STARTING status received a broadcasted recover request
I1102 16:05:39.363711 28016 recover.cpp:195] Received a recover response from a replica in STARTING status
I1102 16:05:39.364202 28007 recover.cpp:566] Updating replica status to VOTING
I1102 16:05:39.364570 28029 leveldb.cpp:306] Persisting metadata (8 bytes) to leveldb took 222611ns
I1102 16:05:39.364594 28029 replica.cpp:323] Persisted replica status to VOTING
I1102 16:05:39.364678 28022 recover.cpp:580] Successfully joined the Paxos group
I1102 16:05:39.364972 28022 recover.cpp:464] Recover process terminated
```

(Data is anonymized somewhat)

It works perfectly the first time I start it, but then hangs forever the second, and I can't figure out why. It must be storing state information somewhere, but `lsof` doesn't show me any files that it could be affecting on any nodes during its run!

Any ideas where to look or what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the system's entropy pool was getting exhausted, and it was blocking on a read to `/dev/random`; It was solved by compiling a new version of the `cyrus-sasl` library to use `/dev/urandom` instead of `/dev/random`, and link my mesos against that.